# wave equation on a square domain

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, wave-equation, music-theory

I'm stuck on the following problem.

> Let $u(x, y, t)$ denote a solution to the linear wave equation
>   $k^2(u_{xx}+u_{yy}) = u_{tt}$ with $k = 2$ on a square domain with
>   corners at (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0) and (1, 1) such that u ≡ 0 on the
>   boundary of the domain. Write down $u(x, y, t)$ if
>
> i)
>
> $u(x,y,0) = \sin(5\pi x)\sin(5 \pi y)$
>
> $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,y,0)= \sin(7 \pi x)\sin(\pi y)$
>
> ii)
>
> $u(x,y,0) = \sin(5\pi x)\sin(5 \pi y) + 3\sin(7\pi x)\sin(\pi y)$
>
> $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,y,0)= 0$

I'll start off with i). I know the solution is of the form

$u(x,y,t) = \sum \sin(\frac{m\pi x}{a}) \sin(\frac{n\pi y}{b})(A_{mn}\cos(\lambda t) + B_{mn}\sin(\lambda t))$

with

$A_{mn} = \frac{4}{ab}\int_0^b \int_0^a u(x,y,0)\sin(\frac{m\pi x}{a})\sin(\frac{n\pi y}{b})dxdy$

and a similar integral for $B_{mn}$. So I put $a=1$ and $b=1$ in and try to find $A$ and $B$. However, when I evaluate the integrals using maple, end up with solutions like

$A_{mn} = \frac{100\sin(m\pi)\sin(n\pi)}{\pi^2(m^2 n^2-25m^2-25n^2+625)}$

$B_{mn} = \frac{28sin(m\pi)sin(n\pi)}{\pi^2(m^2n^2-m^2-49n^2+49)}$

but this seems wrong as this just tells me that $A$ and $B$ are zero for any $m,n$... When I try ii) I get a similar answer - $A$ and $B$ are zero.

have I gone wrong anywhere? Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Im not sure - I got the theory from lecture notes, for example page 12 on here http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-303-linear-partial-differential-equations-fall-2006/lecture-notes/pde3d.pdf

Comment: oh wait yeah thanks, if m=5,n=5 then I get a non zero solution. Forgot to use orthogonality!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: $2 = k = 2\pi/\lambda \Rightarrow \lambda = \pi$

i)
Assuming
$$
u(x,y,t) = 
\sin(5\pi x)\sin(5 \pi y)\cos(\sqrt{200}\pi t) + (1/\sqrt{200}\pi) \sin(7 \pi x)\sin(\pi y)\sin(\sqrt{200}\pi t)
$$

we get
$$
u_t(x,y,t) = 
-\sqrt{200}\pi\sin(5\pi x)\sin(5\pi y)\sin(\sqrt{200}\pi t) + \sin(7\pi x)\sin(\pi y)\cos(\sqrt{200}\pi t)
$$

and
\begin{align}
u(x,y,0) &= \sin(5\pi x)\sin(5 \pi y) \\
u_t(x,y,0) &= \sin(7 \pi x)\sin(\pi y)
\end{align}

Checking the PDE: 
\begin{align}
u_x(x,y,t) &=
5\pi\cos(5\pi x)\sin(5\pi y)\cos(\sqrt{200}\pi t) + 
\frac{7}{\sqrt{200}} \cos(7\pi x)\sin(\pi y)\sin(\sqrt{200}\pi t) \\
u_y(x,y,t) &= 
5\pi \sin(5\pi x)\cos(5\pi y)\cos(\sqrt{200}\pi t) + 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{200}} \sin(7\pi x)\cos(\pi y)\sin(\sqrt{200}\pi t) \\
u_{xx}(x,y,t) &=
-25\pi^2\sin(5\pi x)\sin(5\pi y)\cos(\sqrt{200}\pi t) -
\frac{49\pi}{\sqrt{200}} \sin(7\pi x)\sin(\pi y)\sin(\sqrt{200}\pi t) \\
u_{yy}(x,y,t) &= 
-25\pi^2 \sin(5\pi x)\sin(5\pi y)\cos(\sqrt{200}\pi t) -
\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{200}} \sin(7\pi x)\sin(\pi y)\sin(\sqrt{200}\pi t) \\
u_{tt}(x,y,t) &= 
-200\pi^2\sin(5\pi x)\sin(5\pi y)\cos(\sqrt{200}\pi t) - 
\sqrt{200} \pi\sin(7\pi x)\sin(\pi y)\sin(\sqrt{200}\pi t) 
\end{align}

Then
\begin{align}
4(u_{xx} + u_{yy}) &=
-200\pi^2\sin(5\pi x)\sin(5\pi y)\cos(\sqrt{200}\pi t) - 
\frac{200\pi}{\sqrt{200}}\sin(7\pi x)\sin(\pi y)\sin(\sqrt{200}\pi t) \\
&=
-200\pi^2\sin(5\pi x)\sin(5\pi y)\cos(\sqrt{200}\pi t)-
\sqrt{200}\pi \sin(7\pi x)\sin(\pi y)\sin(\sqrt{200}\pi t) \\
&= u_{tt}
\end{align}

I used the Maxima system to verify this, because I had to revise this a couple of times due to errors I made.

ii)
Using the ansatz
$$
u(x,y,t) = 
\sin(5\pi x)\sin(5\pi y)\cos(L\pi t) + 3 \sin(7\pi x)\sin(\pi y)\cos(M\pi t) 
$$

gives
$$
u_t(x,y,t) = 
-L\pi \sin(5\pi x)\sin(5\pi y)\sin(L\pi t) - 3 M\pi \sin(7\pi x)\sin(\pi y)\sin(M\pi t) 
$$

and one gets
\begin{align}
u(x,y,0) &=
\sin(5\pi x)\sin(5\pi y) + 3 \sin(7\pi x)\sin(\pi y) \\
u_t(x,y,0) &= 0
\end{align}
Second order partial derivatives are:
\begin{align}
u_{xx}(x,y,t) &=
-147\pi^2 \sin(7\pi x)\sin(\pi y)\cos(M\pi t)-
25\pi^2 \sin(5\pi x)\sin(5\pi y)\cos(L\pi t) \\
u_{yy}(x,y,t) &=
-3\pi^2 \sin(7\pi x)\sin(\pi y)\cos(M\pi t)-
25\pi^2 \sin(5\pi x)\sin(5\pi y)\cos(L\pi t) \\
u_{tt}(x,y,t) &=
-3M^2\pi^2 \sin(7\pi x)\sin(\pi y)\cos(M\pi t)-
L^2\pi^2 \sin(5\pi x)\sin(5\pi y)\cos(L\pi t) \\
\end{align}

Comparing both sides of the PDE
\begin{align}
4(u_{xx}+u_{yy}) &= 
-600\pi^2\sin(7\pi x)\sin(\pi y)\cos(M\pi t)-
200\pi^2\sin(5\pi x)\sin(5\pi y)\cos(L\pi t) \\
u_{tt}(x,y,t) &=
-3M^2\pi^2 \sin(7\pi x)\sin(\pi y)\cos(M\pi t)-
L^2\pi^2 \sin(5\pi x)\sin(5\pi y)\cos(L\pi t) \\
\end{align}
gives the conditions $600=3 M^2$ and $200 = L^2$, which means $M = L = \sqrt{200}$ and the solution
$$
u(x,y,t) = 
\left[\sin(5\pi x)\sin(5\pi y) + 3 \sin(7\pi x)\sin(\pi y)\right]
\cos(\sqrt{200}\pi t) 
$$

Comment: Just checked it over to get the same answer myself, thanks for the help! I'll use the theory to do ii).

Comment: So far the results by educated guessing and calculation. :)  Your theoretical solution looked fine, except that it was for $k=1$, so the formulas have to get modified.